# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\bcmul() in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, bitcoin

Here is My code  bcmul is undefined but my concern bcmul is php 
   function using for Multiply two arbitrary precision numbers. 
     but laravel show undefined why?

```
  public function confirmBtcRequest(Request $request,$id){

    $getBalanceInfo = $this->bitcoin->get_balance();
    $sendAmount = bcmul($getBalanceInfo->data->available_balance, '0.01', 8); 
    print_r($sendAmount);
    die;
}
```

if You have any idea please respond me.

Comment: share your Route,view and model if any.

Comment: You might need to install BCMath http://php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php

Comment: ok i try..to install bcmath

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to PHP documentation, BCMath is not available by default with PHP7 on Linux servers.

> bcmath ist not installed automatically with php 7 on linux (ubuntu
>   server) You have to use: sudo apt-get install php-bcmath

Please install it using apt-get: `sudo apt-get install php-bcmath`

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php

Answer (score 4):

bcmul() is a function in php. This error means that the php version on your server has not been compiled with the necessary library, called BC Math (http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php). You need to talk to your server admin about this.